# MySQL выборка со сравнением

Tags: php, mysql

Несколько компьютеров отсылают данные.

Каждая машина отсылает:

```
[Объект 1], Значение А: [некое_число], Значение Б: [некое_число]
[Объект 2], Значение А: [некое_число], Значение Б: [некое_число]
...
```

Объектов может быть аж до 500-600, названия разные.
Однако каждая машина отсылает одинаковые названия для каждого объекта (что логично).

Значений на Объект от одной машины только 2: А и Б.

**Задача:**

Сравнить Значения между Машинами по Объектам так, чтобы вывести данные, если выполнено следующее условие:

```
(Значение А = 2, а Значение Б > 5) или (Значение Б = 2, а Значение А > 5)
или
(Значение А = 3, а значение Б > 6) или (Значение Б = 3, а Значение А > 6)
```

Между всеми машинами. При этом, чтобы сравнение было только между Значениями А и Б (А-А и Б-Б недопустимо), на разных машинах (т.е. А одной машины и Б другой. А и Б одной машины не сравниваются) при одинаковых Объектах (т.е. данные Объекта 1 нельзя сравнивать с данными Объекта 2).

**Пример:**

Таблица с данными:

```
         | Маш 1 | Маш 2 | Маш 3 | Маш 4 |
         | А | Б | А | Б | А | Б | А | Б |
------------------------------------------
Объект 1 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
Объект 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
Объект 3 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
```

По данной таблице должно получится:

```
Объект 2, Маш 4 (Б = 2), Маш 3 (А = 7)
Объект 3, Маш 3 (А = 2), Маш 1 (Б = 6)
Объект 3, Маш 4 (А = 2), Маш 1 (Б = 6)
Объект 2, Маш 2 (Б = 3), Маш 3 (А = 7)
```

Не обязательно в таком формате, главное - название объекта, какая машина, какие данные и по какому значению (А, или Б).

Таблица в БД аналогичная, столбцы: ID (ключ), Объект, Маш1А, Маш1Б, Маш2А ...

Тип поля Объект - char(30), всё остальное - int.

Никак не соображу, как составить запрос так, чтобы сделать такую выборку (каким образом её осуществить).
Или последовательно 2 выборки (при первом = 2, втором более 5 и при первом = 3, втором более 6).

Comment: У вас не правильная структура таблицы, должны быть колонки: `ID, Объект, Машина, A, B` собственно все. каждая запись должна быть представлена соответственно 4 записями, по одной на машину для объекта. Без этого запрос написать конечно можно, но какой то жуткий получается

Comment: Хорошо, Вы предложили структуру таблицы... Но это всё ещё не решило задачи, не натолкнуло на мысль к решению. Вопрос остаётся. Не поймите неправильно, но я не вижу смысла менять формат таблицы "просто так".

Comment: Я это написал что бы понимать с чем иметь дело. 90% спрашивающих не готовы менять структуру ни при каких обстоятельствах, не смотря на то, что с ней невозможно работать средствами SQL. Реляционные БД готовы работать с нормализованными данными https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @Mike Если не трудно, посмотрите запрос в ответе, это запрос только для одного условия из 4-х. Он вообще примерно так должен выглядеть или я не соображаю и можно проще?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Да, я сейчас как раз начал себе пример с нормализованными данными готовить. Сейчас скорее всего, что нибудь более красивое придумаю

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов В любом случае RIGTH там не к чему, обычный join таблицы самой с собой, даже без подзапроса

Comment: @Mike да я перемудрил правда, исправил сейчас, вроде как все одним запросом и со всеми условиями.

Comment: Какие колонки реально нужны на выходе из запроса ? значения которые в скобках (вроде "Б = 2") прямо в таком виде и нужны ?

Comment: Не обязательно, нужны только рабочие поля: название Объекта, какие машины, какие данные и какой-то указатель на то, какие данные подошли (хотя это можно уже в php наверное).

Comment: Т.е. здорово было-бы получить таблицу, где  первая строка Объект, вторая какая машина, третья какое значение (само значение + А, или Б), четвёртая, какая вторая машина и пятая аналогично третьей... Это в идеале, чтобы потом кодом не искать, а уже знать, какие значения подошли, на каких машинах, по каким объектам и что за значения подошли - А, или Б на этих машинах.

Comment: Не знаю, сколько тапков сейчас полетит... В общем подумалось мне с такой структурой без поля "Машина" сделать по таблице на каждую машину... Какие соображения в целесообразности такого подхода? Не слишком топорно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Структура неправильная, действительно, как написал Mike. С предложенной им структурой:

```
ID, Объект, Машина, A, B
```

можно делать такие запросы:

```
SELECT a.object, a.mashina, a.A, a.B, b.object, b.mashina, b.A, b.B
FROM test2 AS a
JOIN test2 AS b 
ON b.id != a.id AND b.object = a.object
WHERE (a.B = 2 AND b.A > 5) 
OR (b.A = 2 AND a.B > 5) 
OR (a.B = 3 AND b.A > 6) 
OR (b.A = 3 AND a.B > 6)
```

UPD. теперь все условия в одном запросе.

Вариант, предложенный Mike:

```
select X.object, X.machine, Y.machine, C,
       case when (X.A=C and Y.B > D) then Y.B else Y.A end
  from test2 X, test2 Y,
       (select 2 C, 5 D union all select 3, 6) Z
 where X.object=Y.object and X.machine!=Y.machine
   and ( (X.A=C and Y.B > D) or (X.B=C and Y.A > D) )
```

Работает так: берутся 2 таблицы, к ним добавляются поля С и D для каждой строчки. вот так:

[image: скриншот таблицы]

То есть каждая строчка дублируется. И потом уже из этой выборки получается нужный результат.

Comment: Данный запрос вроде на Б = 2, а А более 5-и (насколько могу понимать). Т.е. для А = 2 и Б более 5-и, а также для А и Б по условию = 3 и более 6-и делать отдельные выборки? ЗА мысль спасибо, вот теперь изменение структуры БД обоснована.

Comment: Да, простите, все правильно

Comment: @ВладимирВолк Честно говоря, не знаю, есть ли смысл так делать. Здесь, действительно все равно получается 4 выборки разных делать. С Вашей структурой будет одно большое жуткое условие, но почему бы и нет... С точки зрение структуры таблицы правильнее и логичнее выглядит все-таки `ID, Объект, Машина, A, B`

Comment: @ВладимирВолк удалось все сделать одним запросом общими усилиями. Ну и может быть Mike сделает и напишет более простой вариант.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов У меня пока так вышло http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b206e0/1  Но мне сейчас больше интересно какие все таки колонки ожидаются на выходе. Явно ожидают получить меньшее кол-во колонок, но не делать же прямо такой текст как там

Comment: @Mike да, действительно более красивое решение получилось ) Спасибо, возьму на заметку, никогда не приходилось так делать - добавлять поля чтобы по ним же искать )

Comment: @Mike, решение интересное, это правда :) На выходе надо Объект, машина 1, машина 2, Значение 1 и значение 2. Попробую понять Ваш вариант (никогда раньше ничего подобного не видел) :)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, спасибо, вариант понятный, попробую и его :)

Comment: Вопрос (который возможно введёт в ступор): можно-ли сделать так, чтобы выводил не А и Б обеих машин, а только те значения, которые подошли под условие? Может даже с какой подписью (да, это уже слишком, пожалуй) :)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов думаю, Вам стоит свой вариант отдельным ответом запостить, уж больно он интересный :)

Comment: @ВладимирВолк Это, наверное, не мой вариант интересный =). А подпись к полю можно, например, так сделать: вместо `SELECT поле` написать `SELECT CONCAT('ваша_подпись', поле)`.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов спасибо, полезная весч :) На счёт вашего варианта: (select 2 C, 5 D union all select 3, 6) Z <- вот эту строку понять не могу. На самом деле условий 10, как сюда можно добавить третье. И как это вообще работает? О_о Вариант и правда интересный.

Comment: @ВладимирВолк повторюсь, что это не мой вариает, а Mike =) добавил в ответ его вариант с картинкой таблицы, удалю потом если будет нужно =)

Comment: Тогда @Mike добрый человек, запости ответ с этим вариантом :) + объясни тугому значение сей строки -> (select 2 C, 5 D union all select 3, 6) Z. Интересует каким образом сие работает и что такое Z, как вторые данные (3 и 6) берёт и можно-ли добавить более 2-х пар данных?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов благодарствую :) Если ещё про Z объяснишь - вообще отлично. А к конечному виду, как понимаю, через php привести только (убрать те значения А и Б, которые под условие не подходят, а вывелись потому, что потому :) Ибо парные на машину и SQL динамически их при выводе обнулять, например, если не подошли не будет) :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69577/discussion-between---and--).